# Is "vagrant up" possible from different local directories with custom URLs?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have two directories under /var/www/html, named vlp1 and vlp2 with Vagrant setup. If I run `vagrant up` separately in these folders the default local URL is `vagrant.local` for both. But `vagrant.local/` always loads site from vlp1 folder.

As it should be, `vagrant global-status` shows that I have two virtual machines running under these directories. I require to run both sites  side by side and to do this the only option I see is to have separate URLs. I believe there is a way to assign different URLs to different sites but don't have any idea how!

What I need to do to accomplish the above so that my sites run like **local.vlp1.com** and **local.vlp2.com** or may be like **vagrant.vlp1** and **vagrant.vlp2**?

According to project instructions I have to keep two sites completely separated in two folders and have to use separate `Vagrantfiles`.

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- Installed VitualBox version: 5.1
- Installed Vagrant version: 1:1.9.4

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
Went through the following steps as advised by Henri:

**Step 1:**

```
$ vagrant global-status
```

Output:

```
id       name    provider   state   directory                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------
eb9b569  default virtualbox running /var/www/html/vlp1                  
190608c  default virtualbox running /var/www/html/vlp2
```

**Step 2:** Did a graceful shutdown on vlp2

```
$ vagrant halt 190608c
```

**Step 3:** Output of vagrant global-status now is

```
id       name    provider   state    directory                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
eb9b569  default virtualbox running  /var/www/html/vlp1                  
190608c  default virtualbox poweroff /var/www/html/vlp2
```

**Step 4:**

```
$ sudo gedit /var/www/html/vlp2/Vagrantfile

if CONF['ip'] == "dhcp"
    config.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp", hostsupdater: "skip"
else
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.5"
end
```

**Step 5:** Re up'd vlp2 machine

```
$ vagrant up 190608c
```

**Step 6:**
`$ vagrant global-status` now shows both machine are back to running state again.

```
id       name    provider   state   directory                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------
eb9b569  default virtualbox running /var/www/html/vlp1                  
190608c  default virtualbox running /var/www/html/vlp2
```

**Step 7:**
In /etc/hosts added following entry

```
192.168.2.5   vagrant.vlp2
```

Finally I tried vagrant.vlp2/ in browser but ended up with the following message:

> This site can’t be reached
>   http://vagrant.vlp2/ is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you're using multiple VM so the easiest in this case is to assign each of the VM a static IP (that must be different) so you do so in Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.x"
  ...
end
```

and you use another IP for the second VM

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.20.y"
  ...
end
```

and then you update your `/etc/hosts` file with the information

```
192.168.10.x    vagrant.vlp1
192.168.20.y    vagrant.vlp2
```

Comment: Hi Henri, thanks for your quick reply! I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Updated original question with steps I followed. Please let me know what I have did wrong.

Comment: can you ping vagrant.vlp2 ? make sure it resolved the IP (I see you have condition in your vagrantfile) - can you confirm your web server is running in your VM ? can you connect to your site from the VM ?

Comment: A bit of more information. I tried by restarting apache after editing `/etc/hosts`. Now I have two entries in hosts file: `192.168.2.3 vagrant.vlp1` and `192.168.2.5 vagrant.vlp2`. What I have noticed is `192.168.2.3` is my IP address as shown in Connection information, but 192.168.2.5 is something I just put! However, when I run `vagrant.vlp1` it loads default localhost page, and `vagrant.local` still loads the actual site. `vagrant.vlp2` still showing the same thing.

Comment: Ping says "Destination host unreachable". I don't understand this bit "can you confirm your web server is running in your VM ? can you connect to your site from the VM ?" - sorry for my poor knowledge about vagrant. Using this for the first time. Please consider.

Comment: It seems we miss a lot of information to provide good response, you're using vagrant plugin to manage the IP ? the IP of your VM is set dynamically by dhcp from your Vagrantfile - once you run vagrant up - check the IP of the site from the VM and check your site is running from the VM

Comment: run `vagrant ssh` to ssh in the VM and you can run curl or wget against your local site to make sure its up and running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144568/discussion-between-subrata-sarkar-and-frederic-henri).

Comment: I commented out the if-else condition in Vagrantfile and put `config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.5"` outside. Now `vagrant reload xxx` gives me: "The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network! This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of a bridged or non-hostonly network..."

Comment: `vagrant ssh`.  `vagrant@vagrant:~$ wget vagrant.vlp2`

Resolving vagrant.lvp (vagrant.lvp)... failed: Name or service not known. 
wget: unable to resolve host address `vagrant.vlp2'

Comment: from the VM, you need to use the IP unless you set the hostname of your VM to vagrant.vlp2. vagrant.vlp2 is the name you map the IP on your host (so the guest is not aware about this name, unless you tell him somewhere)